# Strict Iptables on docker

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, firewall, docker

Iv'e been trying to configure iptables for a docker (that runs on an ubuntu host). I haven't worked with docker before and I've been informed that docker requires special treatment.

I want to allow only a specific range of ips to be able to connect to the ubuntu machine.

I also want to allow the docker to create ssh/telnet/snmp traffic to the entire network.

Lastly i want to drop All other kind of traffic (to the host and to the docker).

I am not sure where and how I should configure the rules, so they will not interfere with each other (plus, specifically on the docker I am not sure how to use the "docker-user" chain).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two way, one is let docker stop manipulate iptables rules and you take care of it (Personally I do not recommend this way) or use the docker-user chain as you already mention.

As per the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/) says, the docker and docker-user chain are the first used by iptables for filter, so you can configure as default DROP for standard chain (INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD) and add your rules in the DOCKER-USER chain, this is important because is the only chain will not flushed at docker restart, like this you can define your custom rules.

In the DOCKER-USER chain you can define input, output and forward rules as you want just define the interface/ip-address/ip-address range/networks source/destination in the rule added to the chain, for example suppose you have 2 interface **eno1** and **eno2**

an input rule could be:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eno[1|2] -s 192.168.0.0/24 --proto tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

a forward rule could be:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eno[1|2] -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eno[1|2] -d 192.168.138.0/24 --proto tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

an output rule (if you also manage the output traffic) could be:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -o eno[1|2] -d 192.168.0.0/24 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

and so on.

I hope this helps you to clarify your dubt.

Comment: It is!Thank you very much!! If I will add rules to the INPUT chain, and save them to the iptables file, will it remain after restart ?

Comment: I never try that way, but maybe not, I do not think docker service use the ip tables file, it just flush all rules